# Limited wire connection from desk-top

Tags: linux, hp

I have a desktop HP ProLiant comp-server, with ubuntu 12.04 installed. It is connected via wire to my  Comcast modem. A while ago, a video-card in HP stopped  working, but after I pulled it out and then reinstalled, everything got back, with one strange exception: my wire  connection to internet became very limited. I can easily get to most of Google and Yahoo sites, but to nothing else (an error msg "This webpage is not available"). When trying to use "ping" command to check online connection to my office comps, the feedback is "all packages lost"; similarly, all  "ssh" connections were denied. Comcast guys, after checking my modem a few times, told me there nothing wrong with the modem -- the problem is mine. (BTW, I have two laptops, and their  wi-fi works fine.)  Any advice???

Comment: Did you have to install new software/driver to handle the new card? Was it proprietary? Have you checked to see if your network settings (`hosts` file, firewall, DHCP, etc.) have changed? Can a laptop run packet sniffer and "see" the desktop's connection to the modem? Suspect that new card has new software which modified NIC settings invisibly at install and, without a backup prior to install, may be difficult to trace.

Comment: @Gypsy -- thanks. The video-card isn't new; I've just pulled out the old one, then put it back -- and by some miracle, the monitors got alive -- they "saw" my comp again. Will this give you some idea?

Comment: Without being "hands-on" to test I couldn't say what caused it for sure. Often times, especially with proprietary drivers, there's a conflict between devices. Somehow the video card was using a resource (bus address, IRQ, or anything else) that was supposed to be used by the network interface. When the system "reinstalled" the video card it got assigned a new slot it the resources that didn't conflict anymore. The lesson to learn is that look for the last change, or two, when problems "appear", even when it doesn't seem connected. Glad you got it working. Happy computing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I guess I am the most stupid guy around here. The issue was hardware related, or rather simply using a wrong jack. OK, there are two telephone-like wire jacks at the back of the comp, labeled simply 1 and 2. While reconnecting all the plugs & wires (after fixing my video-card problems), I plugged the wire connecting my comp to a modem into the jack #1, which by now turned out to be a mistake. After struggling with all kind of possible ( most of them imaginary) problems, a simple thought to switch the jacks came to my mind (i. e. using #2 instead of #1). ***It worked!!!*** ( It would be helpful if anybody explained to me what is a damn functional difference  between those jacks...)